# Is it possible to use Reduce in a way that "eliminates" some unwanted variables, and only gives constraints between wanted variables?

Tags: equation-solving, constraint, dimension-reduction

`Reduce[{x == z, y == z}]` gives `y == z && x == z` but say I'm only interested in constraints that appear between `x` and `y`.

The desired result of this hypothetical reduce would be. `x==y`. Don't know if it helps, but I'm only working with equalities.

Comment: There's *undocumented* syntax for that specific case: `Reduce[{x == z, y == z}, {x, y}, z]`.

Comment: `Eliminate[{x == y, y == z}, z]`

Comment: @J.M. As with `Solve`, it's best practice to put the eliminated variable(s) in braces, to tell MMA that it's not a domain specification, e.g., `Reduce[{x == z, y == z}, {x, y}, {z}]`.

Comment: @theorist, yes, that's a recent development.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

With `Solve` you can specify a list of variables to be eliminated. The list brackets are required even for a single variable to preclude interpretation as an attempt to specify a domain specification.

```
Solve[{x == z, y == z}, y, {z}][[1]]

(* {y -> x} *)

% /. Rule -> Equal

(* {y == x} *)
```

Comment: Is this documented? Where to find?

Comment: @Acus - It is an outdated capability that still works (presumably for backward compatibility). See [`Version 7`](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/ref/Solve.html) "Solve[eqns, vars, elims] attempts to solve the equations for vars, eliminating the variables elims." There are other uses of it on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

`Eliminate` seems to do the job, but dosent work well when the resulting constraint should be an inequality (for example `y==x*x`, eliminating `x`, I would like to get `y>=0`. The operation `Resolve` with `Exists` over the unwanted variables and `Reals` as domain should get the correct answer, the downside being that quantifier elimination might be computationally expensive.